# Limit custom tiles to certain extent in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, coordinates, web-mapping, extents

I want to fit my custom tiles at a certain region. For example let's say i have custom tiles for a certain country (example: USA) and I am using OSM or anything at all. How do i make sure that my tiles fit a certain extent. I tried putting in the extent but the layer does not load. Please help.

```
map = new Map({
      target: 'map',
      layers: [
        new TileLayer({
          source: new OSM({
            wrapX: false,
          }),
        }),
        new TileLayer({
          extent:[12679211,2560587,12703254,2544509],
          source: new XYZ({
            maxZoom: 16,
            projection: projection,
            tileSize: tileSize,
            tileUrlFunction: function(tileCoord) {
              console.log("--------------")
              console.log("before",tileCoord);
              console.log("after", " z = ",tileCoord[0] - 1," x = ",tileCoord[1]," y = ",(-tileCoord[2] - 1))
              return urlTemplate.replace('{z}', (tileCoord[0] - 1).toString())
                .replace('{x}', tileCoord[1].toString())
                .replace('{y}', (-tileCoord[2] - 1).toString());
            },
            wrapX: false
          })
        }),
      ],
      view: new View({
        center:  [12689317.435763245, 2552726.0298609314  ],
        zoom:13,
        minZoom: 0
      })
    });
```

Comment: What do you see in network debug? Are tiles loading? How is `projection` defined?

Comment: The tiles are not being loaded for this specific extent. However if i do this it works extent:[-13884991, 2870341, -7455066, 6338219]. It does not load the whole image only a certain part of it though but the extent works.

Comment: You didn't answer: how is `projection` defined?

Comment: var projection = get('EPSG:3857');

Comment: Since EPSG 3857 covers the whole world, how are you tiles numbered, let's say four tiles at zoom level 1?

Comment: The layer `extent` option restricts where tile can be displayed, it doesn't position tiles.  If you remove the `extent` option completely do you see the image in the correct place relative to the OSM layer?  If not you will need to specify a `tileGrid`.

Comment: No tiles are being loaded because your extent is invalid, the correct format is [minx, miny, maxx, maxy].and extents can be used for any layer, not just custom tiles  https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-hyicp

Comment: @Mike do you have any examples for the tileGrid, I tried using it but it gives me error.

Comment: @TomazicM does this mean that if i want to have my custom tiles overlay on the world map then i need to name the custom tile depending on the zoom level ?